# Will the cube plugin be available to use in ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: unity, compiz, cube

it is a feature that attract users to come to ubuntu, since it's pretty and most important, efficient.
any hopes it will be available to use in the next unity release 11.10?

Comment: Cube is still there in 11.4 so why would it not be in 11.10? It is buggy ok but it is still there http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/compiz-cube-natty/

Comment: it will be there, but does it work? i'm not gonna mess with config files, the question is : is it gonna work smoothly in the next release? without work arounds... just like it did with gnome 2? unity plugin will still depend on the wall plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is designed to use the Desktop Wall plugin, and I don't see any reason why they would change it. In fact what needs to be changed is the Desktop Cube plugin itself, as it does not support vertical layouts (as the KWin cube does).

Unless someone does the necessary work to add this feature and fix any bugs, it will remain essentially the same as it is in 11.04.

Comment: thanks for the clear answer. who is the responsable for the cube plugin development? is it canonical? can i file a bug in launchpad with this ?

Comment: @suli8 currently as far as I know the Cube plugin is not actually being maintained actively by anyone. There is an initiative under way however for the community to pick up this and other unsupported plugins for further development, and I will try to link to this later. By the way, you can mark your question as solved by clicking the tick on my answer if this answered the question for you.